# How to freely deploy project using firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-hosting

I tried to deploy my project On Firebase with spark plan but i got this error:
Error: Your project facebookfirebaseclone must be on the Blaze (pay-as-you-go) plan to complete this command. Required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com can't be enabled until the upgrade is complete. To upgrade, visit the following URL:
Is there are Free Ways to host my project using firebase

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Cloud Functions now require your project to be on the blaze plan. So you won't be able to deploy them unless you upgrade the plan.
However, you can just deploy your site on Firebase hosting using the following command.

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

Use firebase `deploy --help`,  for more info.

Comment: Removing the `functions` section of the project's `firebase.json` file is also needed, as it seems like Firebase Functions aren't used in this project.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using certain features that require a Blaze plan.

If that is the case then there is no option except switching to the Blaze Plan.